# Which is more secure to validate my form with, Javascript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I have just finished an HTML form with processing in PHP. My form is validated in Javascript, but I was wondering if it would be better to validate my form in PHP. Which would be more secure and efficient?

Comment: If you do not validate in PHP, anyone with JS disabled, like bots, can post anything they want. If you don't want that, use PHP. This will probably not be an issue in most cases, but is best practice.

Comment: Thank you for your advice i will validate it for sure yet .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely JS validation is more friendly and efficient, end user will get instant errors if any. And again, PHP side validation is also necessary, to prevent hacking and it is secure. What if someone just removes your JS validation via any debugger. To conclude, it is good to implement both.

Comment: yes i was confused to do it or not and its my first time but yet i know what to do besides thanks

Answer (score 1):

forms validation is secured only if you use php rather than JavaScript because of the following reasons:-

1) as javascript is a client side language any user can disable it.
2) if you are checking that the data already exists or not in database, this can be done using php easily.
3) using a developers tool any user can easily manipulate the javascript validation process.

Validating using php is secured since it is a server side language and user cannot manipulate the validation process.

Comment: yes thank you guys i just started doing it